# Estimating current draw from alternator (14.4v?) to 12v DC

Tags: current, dc, lead-acid

I'm wiring my caravan into my car this weekend. In order to keep the caravan's leisure battery charged the cars alternator provides a current to the caravan for this purpose.

I need to figure out what gauge wire and fuse I need for this.

Unfortunately my multimeter can only measure up to 10amps DC and I don't want to kill it in the process of measuring the current from the car. I intend to let the leisure battery drop to 12v (about 50% full) at most. I *think* the voltage from the car is about 14.4v for charging the leisure battery, or around that.

I'm not sure how to calculate a current draw between two voltages.. I suppose a lot of it has to do with the fact these are lead acid batteries?

Some guidance would be very much appreciated. I couldn't find the answer on google.

Comment: Will the leisure battery be 80% drain before you start the next trip again?

Answer (score 0):

You need a split charge relay, relevant fuse and good quality wire for 80 amps or so.

This is the type of components that I used for a couple of caravans and the second battery I had on my Landrover that I used for jump-starting other vehicles.

And as for finding info, this link may help :`http://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/split-charging.html`

Answer (score 0):

I hope the notes in:
http://www.vishay.com/docs/30304/currentmeasurement.pdf
and in:
http://www.vishay.com/docs/49159/_power-metal-strip-shunts-current-shunts_vmn-pl0005-1409.pdf
can help you to measure a low voltage and, indirectly, the big current.